# Knowing the sum of a random number of N i.i.d random variables, find the probability of N

Tags: probability

Today I've met a statistical problem which I've found complex enough to deserve a place here,

Let $X$ be an uniform discrete random variable, having $\{1,...,N \}$ for support.

Let $S_n$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, n\in \mathbb N^* $,  be the sum of $n$ i.i.d variables $X_i$ following that same uniform discrete distribution.

My first question is : knowing that this sum is equal to a certain amount k, what is the probability that $n=n_1$, i.e that the sum was one of $n_1$ observations ?

My second question is : How can I find a confidence interval of the 90% most likely values for $n$.

I tend to think that the problem might be rephrased somehow and that it could transform my problem in an easier one, I'll update the post if I find anything.

Comment: I think I am missing something, or misunderstanding your first question: if $X$ cannot take value $0$ (since $X\geq 1$ a.s.), how can the value $k$ taken by $S_n$ (conditioning on it) be achieved by summing  less than the $n+1$ summands?

Comment: Well, you don't know in advance the number of summands. All I know is that the sum equals k. I also know that $Xi \in \{1,,.N\}$. if k <= N, you can obtain k with n = 1 and $X_1=k$. If k-1<=N, you can obtain k with n=2 and $ (X_1,X_2)=(k-1,1)$, etc

Comment: I see... so, it's basically some random variable $Z=\sum_{j=1}^M X_j$, where the distribution of the i.i.d. $X_j$'s is known, but $M$ is itself a r.v.? (And you are looking for $\Pr[ N = n \mid Z =k]$, or something related) No assumption on $M$ is made at all?

Comment: Well, not exactly.. it's more that -with a light change of notation in order to fit the post - : $Z=\sum_{i=1}^i X_i$ is indeed an r.v. With n another r.v. being the number of sumed $X_i$. I am looking for $\Pr[ n = n_1 \mid Z =k]$

Comment: Sorry -- I actually don't see the difference. The r.v. is the number of summands (my $M$, your $n$ -- but $Z$ is then the sum of the $M$ (resp. $n$) first $X_i$'s. Isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, but in any cases, $N$ is the upper bound of the support of the $\{X_i\}$ -not the r.v- and n is the r.v -and not it's realisation

Comment: Oh, sorry -- $N$ in my above comment is a typo, it should be $M$.

Comment: I think you need to fix your notation. $k$ is used for two different things (a summing index and the observed value). Moreover, you have to clarify the relationship between the r.v. $X$ and the number of summands $n$.

And once you're done fixing/clarifying, it would be great if you could write down the probabilities you're trying to compute (like you did in the comments above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find *probability distribution* of $n|S$ (and hence confidence intervals), you need some kind of a prior on $n$. Without it you can do a simple MLE: $S_n$ is approximately $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$ ($\mu=\frac {N+1}2$, $\sigma^2=\frac {N^2-1}{12}>0$) with pdf $f$. Differentiating $\log f$ yields:
$$\left(C-\frac 1 2\log(n)-\frac {(S_n-n\mu)^2}{2n\sigma^2}\right)'=-\frac 1{2n}-\frac 1 {2\sigma^2}\frac{2(S_n-n\mu)(-\mu)n-(S_n-n\mu)^2}{n^2}=0$$
Or
$$X^2+2\mu X-\frac{(\mu+X)\sigma^2}{S_n}=0$$
for $X=S_n/n-\mu$. Solve it for $X$ (careful with the sign) and obtain $n=S_n/(X+\mu)$.

**ETA:** If $\mu=0$, $X=\sigma^2/S_n$ and $n={S_n}^2/\sigma^2$ as expected. For $\mu>0$ and $S_n$ large, we get $$X\approx \sigma^2/(2S_n)$$ and $$n\approx \frac {S_n}\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu^2}$$

Comment: There is a prior on $n$, it's discrete uniform

Comment: @MTur It's not stated anywhere in the problem or comments.